# clicking div except one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with div clicking.

**Example :**

```
<div class="search">
     <div class="row">

     </div>
     <div class="row1">
         DROPDOWN
     </div>
</div>
```

Attempted jQuery:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if(! $(e.target).hasClass('.row')){
        console.log('clicked on something that has not the class theDIV');
    }
});
```

I want when I click somewhere on search or whole body, to row hide his dropdown(row1).
Images :

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I tried this,and all I found on stackoverflow, but nothing help
$('body').click(function(e){
    if(! $(e.target).hasClass('.row')){
      console.log('clicked on something that has not the class theDIV');
    }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').click(function(e){ 
    var target = $(e.target);  
    if (target.is(".search") && $('.row1').is(':visible')) {
        $('.row1').hide();
    }
    else if(target.is(".search") && !$('.row1').is(':visible')) {
        $('.row1').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".search").click(function(){

    $(".row1").fadeOut()

}) })
```

Comment: but this is wrong, because row1 is dropdown, and when i click to "open" dropdown, with this function row1 will immediately close